# Largest Army in Settlers of Catan: Cities and Knights

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

We were playing [Cities and Knights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cities_and_Knights_of_Catan) at the weekend and halfway through the game realised that no one had earned the largest army card.  The reason behind this was that no one knew what it was earned for.  A couple of us scanned through the rule book in search of the answer, but to no avail.

Having since looked at the Wikipedia page (linked above) I see that it's the player with the most knight points, but do the knights have to be active, and is there a minimum requirement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The **Largest Army** card is not used in **Cities and Knights**.

See the [rulebook](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?CaK_rv_Rules_091907.pdf) p2, under "What you need from your Settlers game"

> Set aside  ...
>
> - The Largest Army card

Comment: Hmm!  The depressing thing is that we played the game correctly then - it took a g e s :-)  We'll have to play with the suggestions from here next time: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/settlers-of-catan-play-takes-hours

Comment: I find playing with new players nearly doubles the time to play Cities and Knights (two and a bit hours instead of one and a bit). Your next game is likely to be much quicker.

Answer (score 4):

As Pat indicates in his answer, the Largest Army card is not used.

The second part of this question hints at the **Defender of Catan** points that are awarded, which sort of take the place of Largest Army. When the barbarians reach Catan, if the total strength of active knights equals or exceeds the total number of cities, the player with the most total strength in active knights receives one permanent VP. (If the total strength of active knights is not enough, the player with the least strength has a city sacked, downgrading it to a settlement.) See p. 11 of the [rulebook](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?CaK_rv_Rules_091907.pdf).